# how to use shell to split string into correct format?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, command-line

I have this file with time duration. Some have days but mostly in hh:mm form. The entire form is dd+hh:mm
I was trying to "tr -s '+:' ':'" them into dd:hh:mm form and then split($1,tm,":")calculate them into seconds.
However, the problem I am facing is that after this operation, the form with hh:mm would have hh in tm[1] but if its dd:hh:mm then the tm[1] would be dd. 
Is there a way to put the hh in form of hh:mm into tm[2] and put tm[1] to be 0 Please?

```
4+11:26 
10+06:54 
20:27
```

is the input

the output I wanted would be(in form of tm[1], tm[2], tm[3]):

```
4 11 26 
10 06 54 
0 20 27
```

Comment: Please show what input you have and what output you expect.

Comment: Just added. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: I would first try to normalize the input by inserting missing days and then continue from there in sed: `sed '/+/! s/^/0+/; s/[+:]/ /g;' yourfile`

Comment: That does work! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would first preprocess it with sed (to add missing `0+` in lines that don't have a plus sign) and then `tr` `+:` to spaces:

```
cat a.txt | sed 's/^\([^+]\+\)$/0+\1/g' | tr  '+:' '  '
```

Or as suggested by Lars, shorter `sed` version:

```
cat a.txt | sed '/+/! s/^/0+/;' | tr  '+:' '  '
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

You can do the conversion and computation in `awk`, using your input file the values are converted to minutes

```
$ awk -F: '{if($1~/+/){split($1,f,"+");h=f[1]*24+f[2]}
            else h=$1; m=h*60+$2; print $0 " --> " m}' file

4+11:26  --> 6446
10+06:54  --> 14814
20:27 --> 1227
```